# Questions about tear in spacetime

Tags: general-relativity, spacetime, relativity

Sorry if there's any mistake in the language.

In Einstein's General Relativity Theory gravity is described as the curvature of the spacetime fabric. So can analogous to a real fabric can this spacetime fabric also tear?

In a gravitation field where spacetime is curved time slows down. So what happens to the point in spacetime where it is torn? What causes the spacetime to tear?

Comment: Did you read somewhere about "tearing" of space-time or is that just your assumption?

Comment: @harshit54 It's just my assumption. If it can curve then can't it tear?